# TestNG skipped classes once one test class is failed

Tags: testng

I am using testng to run a package which contains about 20 test classes, my xml file is like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="PageTest" parallel="classes" thread-count="5"> 
    <packages>  
        <package name="testpagename"/>         
    </packages> 
</test>     
</suite>
```

and my test classes are defined as

```
public class testdemo {
    @BeforeClass    
    public void setUpClass(){       

    }
    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass(){
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1(){
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"testMethod1"})
    public void testMethod2(){
    }

}
```

While the test is running, for some reason, one of the test class is failed because of an unexpected exception, I am expecting that the following test classes are kept running until all of the classes are executed. But indeed, the rest of classes are skipped because of the failure, can anybody show me how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: All classes won't be skipped, only the dependent methods should be skipped.  Is there a relation between this class and the other classes or are those completely independent classes?

Answer (score 0):

Put complete code in try block and use catch block to make it fail by assert statement. So the next TestNG method will not get afftected by the previous failure.

```
@Test
Public void method1(){
try{
// Here will ur code which may cause exception
}
Catch(Exception e){
   Assert.fail("  ");
}
}
@Test
Public void method2{
// implement in same way as method 1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess all following classes will be skipped in case of a @Before* method failure. Try to use configfailurepolicy="continue" attribute in your suite definition.

Comment: Hi, Yes, I think you are right. but once I add the configfailurepolicy="continue" to the suite definition, once the @beforeclass annonation failed, it will only run the tests without dependency in the children classes, is it expected?

Comment: @user3204645 please, rephrase the question. What are tests without dependency? What are children classes? Some kind on an example will really help...

Answer (score 0):

It is specified in the TestNG documentation that we can create dependencies in two ways :

1.Hard dependencies. All the methods you depend on must have run and succeeded for you to run. If at least one failure occurred in your dependencies, you will not be invoked and marked as a SKIP in the report.

2.**Soft dependencies.** This is the one you asked for. You will always be run after the methods you depend on, even if some of them have failed. This is useful when you just want to make sure that your test methods are run in a certain order but their success doesn't really depend on the success of others. A soft dependency is obtained by adding "alwaysRun=true" in your @Test annotation.

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"testMethod1"},alwaysRun=true)
public void testMethod2(){
}
```